# The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element or the style selector of form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email

I'm building a restaurant website and am doing the reservations page. I'm using my own custom form and using EmailJs to send the data from the reservations inputs to my email. When I fill out the form it gives me an error the 3rd parameter of the sendform function from emailjs is expected to be the html form element or the style selector of a form. My code below.

```
import diningroom from "../images/diningroom.jpg";
import { init, sendForm } from 'emailjs-com';
init('DlhTOjdE7Pqq5UJHA');

function Reservations() {
  const initialState = {
    lastname: "",
    guests: "",
    phone: "",
    date: "",
    time: "",
  };

  const [reservation, setReservation] = useState(initialState);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
 
    e.preventDefault();
  sendForm('Carmellos_Reservation','template_9oxce3q','#lastname','#amount','#guests','#phone','#day','#time')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
      setReservation(...reservation,initialState)
    }, function(error) {
      console.log('FAILED...', error);
    });
}
  

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setReservation({
      ...reservation,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="reservation-container">
        <h2 className="reservations">Reservations</h2>
        <p className="parag">
          
          For Reservations Please call 434 977 5200 or Please fill out the form
          Below.
        </p>

        <div
          className="container"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${diningroom})` }}
          c
        >
          <p className="paragraph">
            Carmello's is open for dinner only. Our hours are Tuesday-Saturday
            from 5pm to 9:30pm and on Sundays 5 til 9pm
          </p>
          <p className="paragraph">
            We can accomadate a reservation of 2 persons to large parties. The
            restaurant is available for wedding rehearsals and private parties.
            Please contact Stella Hedges regarding large parties. Reservations
            are strongly urged on the Weekends and we do accept customers as
            walkins. For any reservation greater than 10 please call the
            restuarant directly.
          </p>
          <div className="form-div">
            <form className="reservation-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor="lastname">LastName</label>  
              <input
                type="text"
                name="lastname"
                value={reservation.lastname}
                id="lastname"
                onChange={onChange}
                placeholder="Last Name"
                required
              />
              <label htmlFor="amount"> Amount of Guests</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                name="amount"
                value={reservation.amount}
                id="amount"
                onChange={onChange}
                placeholder="Amount of Guests"
                required
              />
              <label htmlFor="phone">Phone Number</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="phone"
                value={reservation.phone}
                id="phone"
                onChange={onChange}
                placeholder="Phone Number"
                required
              />
              <label htmlFor="date" > Day</label>
              <input
                type="date"
                name="date"
                value={reservation.day}
                id="date"
                onChange={onChange}
                placeholder="Date"
                required
              />
              <label htmlFor="time" >Time</label> 
              <input
                type="time"
                name="time"
                value={reservation.time}
                id="time"
                onChange={onChange}
                min="17:00"
                max="21:00"
                placeholder="time"
                required
              />
              <div className="div-button">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">
                  Make Reservation
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Reservations;
```

Comment: Your 3rd parameter is not the form element like you said, you're passing the id value of one of the inputs.  Try passing in the id of the form element (which you will have to create).

Comment: @PsiKai Thank you. I have a form already built I am not using reacts form hook. I tried passing an id that is on the form tag but still get the same error message.

Comment: Ok if that doesn't work, you can apply a ref to the form element and pass the `ref.current` to that parameter.  The ref will be the form element itself, which is likely what you need.

Comment: Ty @PsiKai Im going to try it now.

Comment: @PsiKai TY TY TY TY Your the man. The useref fixed it!!!!!!!Thanks again!

Comment: Sweet!  Go ahead and create your own answer to this question and mark it as accepted.  Will be a good reference for people who have this issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SendForm=()=> {
    
            3th- form.current
        }

      return(
        <form onSubmit={sendForm} ref={form}
```

> form.current get info from "form" and put in template params

> of corse that we need create a ref to pass the function argument

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter after `'template_9oxce3q'` is te one tat should be of type HTMLFormElement ence maybe in this case `e.target as HTMLFormElement`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use react hook 'useRef()'.
https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/ this should be all you need

Comment: Although your answer may be 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Answer (score 0):

Like @Psikai said, you edit your onSubmit function as written below:

```
 
    e.preventDefault();
  sendForm('Carmellos_Reservation','template_9oxce3q',e.target, 'DlhTOjdE7Pqq5UJHA' )
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
      setReservation(...reservation,initialState)
    }, function(error) {
      console.log('FAILED...', error);
    });
}
```

This will work as it worked for me. Note I assumed 'DlhTOjdE7Pqq5UJHA' is your PUBLIC_KEY. By the way, I didn't add the init 'DlhTOjdE7Pqq5UJHA' when I wrote mine probably because I had the emailjs `<script>` tag already placed inside my index.html and the script tag contains my PUBLIC_KEY