# EmailJS error(React/Typescript): Uncaught The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element or the style selector of form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

My code is below. I keep getting the error "Uncaught The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element or the style selector of form". I think the problem is the 'const fc = form.current!'. But I'm not sure how else to code it. Can someone help me please.

```
const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
const form = useRef<HTMLFormElement | null>(null);

  const closeModal = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (modalRef.current === e.target) {
      setShowModal(false);
    }
  };

  const REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID: string = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID!;

  const REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID: string = process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID!;

  const fc = form.current!;

  const REACT_APP_USER_ID: string = process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ID!;

  const sendEmail = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID,
        REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID,
        fc,
        REACT_APP_USER_ID
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result);
          console.log(form.current);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );

    (e.target as HTMLFormElement).reset();
  };
```

Comment: What research have you done, here or on the wild internet? This exact error message gets many hits. For example https://stackoverflow.com/q/71356056/437212 If these other Q&A do not address your question, then make sure you [edit] this one and tell us why not.

Comment: @clvrmnky I had already seen that question on stackoverflow. Their answer didn't solve my problem. I'm a beginner with typescript and my code was fine until I refactored to typescript. I ended up figuring out my bug and my code works fine now. Thanks anyway

Comment: "If these other Q&A do not address your question, then make sure you [edit] this one and tell us why not." You need to communicate to us what research you have done in order to not waste other people's time. You should [edit] this question now to put these details from the comment into the body of the question in proper context because comments are not part of Q&A. It's ok to be a beginner -- we all are at various points in our life -- but learning how to ask good questions is worth learning now. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask